# Std::ios::in Is 'in' a variable inside ios namespace?

Tags: c++, class, namespaces, std, flags

I have always had this doubt about namespace std. My conclusion is that all class and function declarations in the standard header files shipped with the compiler(g++) are actually inside a namespace called 'std'. So each time the developer made a new header file they would start of like

```
Namespace std {
```

Am I right ?

Is ios::in   a variable inside the ios namespace or is ios a class and 'in' a static variable of some type ?
If yes, does it have an integer value of some kind that instructs the open member function to open a file to be read ?

What do you mean by an ios  flag ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The use of namespace std for all identifiers of th C++ standard
>   library was introduced   during the standardization process. So saying
>   that namespace std holds all the class   shipped with the compiler is
>   correct.Backward compatible is also provided by including    C header
>   files. (example #include )

ios class is derived from ios_base class which has [opening mode flag](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/ios_base) eg. in,out etc.

These stream opening mode flag are `static const public member` of `ios_base class` and can be directly accessed by calling their names as `ios_base::in` or by the class derived from ios_base class. `ios` class is derived from `ios_base` so stream opening flag can be accessed as `ios::in`.

Comment: So if 'in' is a strongly typed variable that is a static constant public member of ios class then what is its data type? Does it have a value?

Comment: openmodeflag's are [BitmaskType](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/BitmaskType). BitmaskType are implementation defined and the value of each [flag](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/ios_base/openmode) is also implementation defined. All the openmode flag belong to `ios_base class` not to `ios class`